# How to set cookies from server in IOS?

Tags: ios, node.js, reactjs, express, cookies

I am setting cookies in express server with code:

```
return res
  .cookie("access_token", token, {
     httpOnly: true,
     maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 7 * 2, // 2 weeks
     sameSite: 'none',
     secure: true
  })
  .status(201)
  .send();
```

It is working well in PC, Android browsers, but not in IOS. I know that IOS blocking third-party cookies, and I can disable it, but how can I set them by default?

P.S. I have client side and server in different Vercel domains.

I tried to test different cookie options, but nothing worked.

Comment: You cannot set third-party cookies if the browser blocks them.